# Differentiate between exceptions raised by python and C++ using boost python

Tags: python, c++, exception, boost-python

I have a C++ code which loads a python script and allows to call C++ functions using the script using boost-python. It catches exceptions as follows:

```
try
{
// some function which might raise an exception
}
catch (const py::error_already_set& e)
{
// handle exception
}
```

The exceptions can be raised by C++ by calling std::runtime_error 
or 
can be raised by the python script (say function not defined)

I want to know how to differentiate if the exception is raised by a C++ code or some syntax issue in my python script. Is there any way to do that in the above catch block?

Comment: With a bit of difficulty, I suppose. My current line of thinking is overriding most of [the default handlers](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/develop/src/errors.cpp#L19) by providing your own translator functions that create something you can recognise and possibly inject other useful information. [Here](https://pastebin.com/UBQXGttZ) is the current state of my experiments with this (I added ability to get the c++ stack trace injected when the exception carries it). Next I want to look at using custom python exception classes that derive from the exceptions currently used.